# How can I modify a variable on another site?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

My son is doing times tables practice on this page, a timed test in which he gets 10 seconds for each sum.

https://www.timestables.com/speed-test/ - this is not my site or code, I have no direct control over the source code.

I want to give him a little more time per sum but I cannot find a way to modify the relevant code and make it work with 20 seconds instead of 10.

It looks to me like the relevant variable is maxTime (milliseconds) in this function, but nothing I do using the Chrome Developer Tools will modify this in a live running page to give 20 seconds instead of 10.

```
function startSom(){


    vraagnr = vraagnr + 1;
    if(vraagnr <= totaalSommen)
    {
        bezig = true;
        $('#pbar_innerdiv').stop();
        $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width","100%");
        $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("backgroundColor","#33BF00");
        $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("borderColor","#33BF00");
        if(mobiel){
        $("#antwVak").html("");
        }
        else{
            $("#antwoordI").val("");
            $("#antwoordI").focus();    
        }
        $('#pbar_innerdiv').stop();

        start = new Date();
        maxTime = 10000;
        timeoutVal = Math.floor(maxTime/100);
          var somT = sommen[vraagnr-1].split(",");
                $('#somVak').html(somT[1]+"×"+somT[0]+"=");
                $('#voortgangVak').html("Question "+vraagnr+" / "+totaalSommen+"<br />"+ punten + " points");

        animateUpdate();
        started = false;
    }
    else
    {
        showEindScherm();

    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest what to do please?

Comment: You cant change a local variable in a function. If it was using a global variable and not setting it in the local scope you might have more luck

Comment: as @Jamiec said it is not possible to change variables via console (imagine the security risks if you could do so!). You might only **change** this value in devtools by setting a break point and **modifying your value manually** throught the console.

Comment: I know it's long winded but why not build a replica app yourself? wouldn't be that difficult

Comment: @Pixelomo - ha that's funny.  All my software projects seem like they'll take "just a couple of weeks to get a bare bones version built" and six months or a year or two later I'm still going.  I no longer believe it when I tell myself I can be write *any* software quickly. I'm just looking for a hack to make it 20 seconds instead of 10, otherwise I'll end up spending months on it.

Comment: I managed to lengthen the time by completely overwriting the `window.startSom` method. Interestingly somewhere else controls the countdown bar.

Comment: @Jamiec hey rocking!  Can I trouble you to bullet point the steps please?

Comment: There are about a billion times tables testers online. Many of which are configurable. Why have you chosen this one?

Comment: @jamiec - this one seems perfect for where he is at, except for the one factor - time.

Comment: They're all pretty perfect ... its only times tables. Theres only so many ways you can learn/practice that.

Comment: @DukeDougal yeah I know pretty stupid suggestion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy the entire method, pase it into chrome devtools and change

```
 function startSom() {
```

to

```
window.startSom = function() {
```

And obviously change your time from 10000 to 20000. This changes the amount of time it allows you to answer, but not the moving progress bar which will still only take 10 seconds.

Comment: Where exactly would I paste it in DevTools?

Comment: the console has a little `>` at the bottom where you can paste statements to be evaluated

Comment: Also take a look on the `animateUpdate` function there. The value 10000 is hardcoded there, so without changes the progressbar will always expire in 10 secs

Answer (score 1):

Please paste this:

```
window.startSom = function(){


    vraagnr = vraagnr + 1;
    if(vraagnr <= totaalSommen)
    {
        bezig = true;
        $('#pbar_innerdiv').stop();
        $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width","100%");
        $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("backgroundColor","#33BF00");
        $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("borderColor","#33BF00");
        if(mobiel){
        $("#antwVak").html("");
        }
        else{
            $("#antwoordI").val("");
            $("#antwoordI").focus();    
        }
        $('#pbar_innerdiv').stop();

        start = new Date();
        maxTime = 20000;
        timeoutVal = Math.floor(maxTime/100);
          var somT = sommen[vraagnr-1].split(",");
                $('#somVak').html(somT[1]+"×"+somT[0]+"=");
                $('#voortgangVak').html("Question "+vraagnr+" / "+totaalSommen+"<br />"+ punten + " points");

        animateUpdate();
        started = false;
    }
    else
    {
        showEindScherm();

    }
}
```

Here:
[image]

And if you want to make the progress bar following the new max Time, also paste this:

```
window.animateUpdate = function() {
    if(bezig)
    {
    var now = new Date();

    var timeDiff = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
    if(!started){
        $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width", (100) + "%");
        $('#pbar_innerdiv').animate({width: 0 + "%"},20000);

        started = true;
    }
    perc = Math.round((timeDiff/maxTime)*100);


        console.log(perc);

        if(perc == 33)
        {                           
            $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("backgroundColor", "#FF9500");
            $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("borderColor", "#FF9500");
        }
        if(perc== 66)
        {
            $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("backgroundColor", "#FF0000");
            $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("borderColor", "#FF0000");
        }
      if (perc <= 100) {
       //updateProgress(perc);
       setTimeout(animateUpdate, timeoutVal);

      } 
      else
      {
        bezig = false;
        showTeLaat();
        //alert("tijd is om");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SemirDeljić, how u find out that js file ?

Comment: @nisar I've inspected the page source. It is not in the js file but in the document itself. Press CTRL + u on Windows, and then CTRL + F to search for variable maxTime.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to change files persistently in chrome devtools: [Overrides](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides).

If the script is in a seperate file you can change the maxTime directly there or if it is in a file, which needs to be reloaded you can edit any other .js and add an eventlistener there to change the startSom method on page load.